# ffmpeg over https fails

Tags: ffmpeg

If I feed url with http, such as this:

```
ffmpeg -i http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4 videojs.mp4
```

It works perfectly. However, when I feed url with https, such as this:

```
ffmpeg -i https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/check.mp4 video.mp4
```

This gives me an error:

```
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls, or securetransport enabled.
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/check.mp4: Protocol not found
```

However the same commands works on my windows machine. I am using ubuntu inside a virtualbox and not very good at it.

What do I do to enable https? I suppose I should recompile ffmpeg with openssl? Please help me solve this. Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using 15.04 or something older?

Comment: @ThomasW. No I am using 14.04

Comment: ehh, 14.04 is... old enough that I think ffmpeg was broken... I'll poke at this and see if I can make it build as is in 15.04 and later... later, around my work break.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely what's happening is that `ffmpeg` is compiled without SSL support in the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Whatever the reason for this, it's a headache, so the only solution you have left to rapidly fix this is to actually do a recompile.

Likely, when you build from source, you'll need to have a `--with-openssl` or similar option when you run a `./configure`.

---

Note that for Ubuntu Wily, it appears they may already include this option in the packaging which is newer than for Vivid.

Comment: Sorry this is really a noob question, but how to recompile ffmpeg?

Comment: seems like Wily doesn't include this option by default too http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/ffmpeg/wily/view/head:/configure

Answer (score 0):

Just download ffmpeg from here and you will be fine.
http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
It is build statically and does not need any dependency. Extract it into a folder and run it from that directory with **./ffmpeg** ...